# How can I add non-breaking space to a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to display an array of strings in HTML with a random number of white spaces  in front of the string in the array. How would I go about doing this in JavaScript?

I first did a loop of the array and tried adding  "   " to each string in the array, but the white spaces don't show up. I also tried adding &nbsp;, but it doesn't get interpreted in JavaScript.

Comment: What you do seems to be correct. A simple code sample might help get clarity on the issue you are facing. I am adding '&nbsp;' to a string with no javascript problems. https://jsfiddle.net/d2btyr5k/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding non-breaking spaces should work.

However, the crucial part of displaying white space in an HTML document is to set the [`white-space` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) of the relevant elements to `pre` or `pre-wrap`.